# Multipart File Upload failing with new IntelliJ HTTP Client

Tags: intellij-idea, file-upload, resteasy, rest-client

I´m trying to get a file upload to my JAX-RS controller working with multipart. I´ve been using the integrated REST HTTP Client of IntelliJ, that is recommending me to switch to the new HTTP Client by using .http files.

[image]

However, once I´m doing that I´m unable to do any uploads and I´m running into this exception

**exception**

java.io.IOException: RESTEASY007550: Unable to get boundary for multipart

**request.http**

```
POST http://localhost:8080/content/upload
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: multipart/form-data

--null


< path/to/my/file

--null--
```

What is the correct syntax for performing multipart uploads?

Comment: If you need only the file to be sent, you can omit the boundaries. Apart from that, `Accept-Encoding: multipart/form-data` looks weird, is it what you intended to write? You can find samples of such requests here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-40441 I cannot reproduce the issue you are having even with your request: https://recordit.co/0HLxOyClHM

Answer (score 3):

Here's my `.http` file. Worked.

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/dataSource/1/table/
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=WebAppBoundary

--WebAppBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csv_files"; filename="insight_modeling_base_node.csv"

< /home/core/Code/work/KG_test/data/insight_modeling_base_node.csv
--WebAppBoundary--
```

In your case, try adding `boundary=null`. Or just copy what I pasted here and make some adaptation.